# Convert JSON object to Java object with different format using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have a response that returns a json object in following format:

```
{
    "playerId": "001",
    "name": "michel",
    "age": 21,
    "nation": "USA",
    "ratings": [
        {
            "type": "speed",
            "score": "0121"
        },
        {
            "type": "accuracy",
            "score": "85"
        }
    ],
    "teaminfo": {
        "teamName": "HON",
        "isValid": "true"
    }
}
```

and I have a Java Class as :

```
public class MyRider {
    public String playerId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String speed;
    public String accuracy;
    public String teamName;
    public String isValid;
    //getter, setter... 
}
```

I want to map the JSON object into Java object using GSON.

I tried using `JsonDeserializationContext` deserialize, and it returned `null` for the nested values in JSON.

Comment: Thanks Justin for refactoring the question.

Comment: what did you mean by different format ?

Comment: can you update your code?

Comment: @benjaminc: In json has list of type and score, but in java class its individual string eg. type: speed  turns into string speed and score is its value.

Comment: @deadpool : what kind of update do you need ?

Comment: Code that you are mapping to json string to java object and also list can not be deserialized into variables, you should map to either list of pojo or list of map

Comment: "I tried using JsonDeserializationContext deserialize...". How? Can you add the code for that?

Comment: To make your life easy you have to adjust either JSON to match the Java object or adjust Java object (and create ratings and teaminfo subobjects) to match JSON.  My vote is on changing JSON so it maps exactly to the Java object and you can deserialize it easily.

Comment: Have you tried  using fromJson(String json, Class classOfT) ?. For instance, String jsonString = "{\"playerId\":\"001\",\"name\":\"michel\", \"age\":\"21\"}";
    MyRider myRider = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyRider.class);

Answer (score 3):

### Without custom deserializer

If you cannot change the JSON to return exactly what you want, I suggest you create classes to match it:

MyRider:

```
public class MyRider {
    private String playerId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String nation;
    private List<Rating> ratings;
    private TeamInfo teaminfo;

    // getters, setters, toString override
}
```

Rating:

```
public class Rating {
    private String type;
    private String score;

    // getters, setters, toString override
}
```

TeamInfo:

```
private static class TeamInfo {
    private String teamName;
    private String isValid;

    // getters, setters, toString override
}
```

Then simply deserialize as normal:

```
MyRider rider = gson.fromJson(json, MyRider.class);
```

If you need exactly the fields you've specified in MyRider in your question, consider a transformer class to map the full class above to your needs.

### With custom deserializer

It's also possible to do this with a custom deserializer, but slightly pointless as GSON provides the normal mapping for you which you can then adapt.

Here is an example with a deserializer:

```
public class MyRiderDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyRider> {

    @Override
    public MyRider deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                               JsonDeserializationContext context)
                               throws JsonParseException {
        MyRider rider = new MyRider();
        if(json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject riderObj = json.getAsJsonObject();

            rider.setPlayerId(riderObj.get("playerId").getAsString());
            rider.setName(riderObj.get("name").getAsString());
            rider.setAge(riderObj.get("age").getAsInt());

            JsonArray ratingsArray = riderObj.get("ratings").getAsJsonArray();
            for(JsonElement ratingElem : ratingsArray) {
                JsonObject ratingObj = ratingElem.getAsJsonObject();
                String type = ratingObj.get("type").getAsString();
                switch(type) {
                    case "speed":
                        rider.setSpeed(ratingObj.get("score").getAsString());
                        break;
                    case "accuracy":
                        rider.setAccuracy(ratingObj.get("score").getAsString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            JsonObject teamInfo = riderObj.get("teaminfo").getAsJsonObject();
            rider.setTeamName(teamInfo.get("teamName").getAsString());
            rider.setIsValid(teamInfo.get("isValid").getAsString());

        }
        return rider;
    }
}
```

Note this does not include any checks to validate whether the properties are actually there and is the simplest possible custom deserializer I could think of. To use it, you must register the type adapter at `Gson` creation time:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyRider.class, new MyRiderDeserializer())
                .create();

MyRider myRider = gson.fromJson(reader, MyRider.class);
```